# Where should I write logic to get menu from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Asp.Net MVC 3.0 and I have my _layout.cshtml in Shared folder. Problem is I want to generate menus in this .cshtml which should be loaded from database. But as I understand _layout.cshtml won't have any action etc associated where I can write logic and I don't want to write all this code in cshtml itself. Are there any options to write logic for cshtml within Shared folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a Controller and a view to render the menu and call it inside the `_layout.cshtml`.

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Index", "Menus");  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Eranga is correct, but let me expand on his answer, to answer your question specifically.

What you can do is create a new controller ("menus" for example), and create an action called default.  Have this action return a view, calling it whatever you would like.  Now go to your shared folder and add the view using the name you just specified.

Now for the cool part.  By default, the MVC framework will look in the controllername/viewname path first, and if it fails it will then look at your shared/viewname path, which is where the view you just created resides!  Neat, huh? ;p

Check out http://www.aspnetmvcninja.com/views/view-search-paths for more info on MVC search paths.

Answer (score 0):

@Eranga has given you a good head start on implementing the feature you requested. I think the below two articles will be helpful as well:

> Html.RenderAction and Html.Action:
>
> http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx
>
> A sample implementation of `Html.Action` method with caching:
>
> http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/donut-hole-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-by-using-child-actions-and-outputcacheattribute